# Saving a text file from Citrix session to client machine

Tags: citrix

I've a requirement to save a text file from the citrix session to the client machine. So the published machine runs an executable and that executable 'knows' where the client machine is and can save the text file onto it.

I've tried to save it using the equivalent of \tsclient share as outlined in this [pretty old article](https://desk.zoho.com/portal/advanceprotechnologies/en/kb/articles/how-to-configure-access-to-your-local-computer-s-drives-from-a-citrix-app). I couldn't get it to work - the published executable couldn't see the filepath back to the client.

Failing this a programmatic solution would be good - we own the published executable so we can amend it.

Many thanks for any / all help

**EDIT**

Just to emphasize- I don't expect anyone to write this code for me, but some pointers to how it would be possible with decent references would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Hello there! Have you explored the file transfer options defined within Citrix security policies? There should be an easy way to create a link between the session and a path on the client device if the policies are allowing it.

Comment: Did you check if the "client drive mapping" is enabled on the server?

Comment: @tifi90 thanks. I did check. It is enabled

Comment: I assume you tried to do it manually and it worked. Is this right? What is the clients save path you use? Do you just go for ```c:\\user\\temp\\...```? I assume it might work if you use the clients IP. ```string savePath = "\\192.168.0.1\\user\\temp\\...."```.